# ECMAScript 6 amazon lambda image processing

Tags: ecmascript-6, amazon-web-services

I use this script in amazon lambda for image processing. Script should do:

1. download image and watermark from amazon S3
2. resize image to two sizes
3. put watermark on it and annotate with text
4. put resized and watermarked image to other bucket
5. send to external host some metadata info

At this moment it works as expected, but looks ugly and not robust.

```
let config = {
    watermark : 'watermark.png',
    hostname: 'host-to-ping.com',
    port:'80',
    thumbBucket: 'thumb.bucket.name'
};
let aws = require('aws-sdk');
let s3 = new aws.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
let im = require('imagemagick');
let fs = require('fs');
let mainFile = '/tmp/img.jpg';
let watermarkFile = '/tmp/watermark.png';
let http = require('http');

const getObjectPromise = (params, fileName) => {
    return function (resolve, reject) {
        s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                const message = `Error getting object ${key} from bucket ${bucket}.`;
                reject(message);
            } else {
                fs.writeFileSync(fileName, data.Body);
                resolve({file: fileName, data : data});
            }
        });
    }
};

const getResizePromise = (data, width) => {
    return function (resolve, reject) {

        const resizedFile = `/tmp/resized-${width}.jpg`;
        var event = {};
        event.width = width;
        event.srcData = data.Body;
        event.dstPath = resizedFile;
        try {
            im.resize(event, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    resolve(resizedFile);
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    }
};

const getWatermarkPromise= (file, watermark, annotation) => {
    function identity(tmpFile, callback) {
        im.identify(tmpFile, (err, output) => {
            callback(output);
        });
    }

    return function (resolve, reject) {
        var exec = require('child_process').exec;
        try {
            identity(file, function (out) {
                var h = out.geometry.split(/[x\+]/)
                var size = parseInt(h[1] * 0.70);

                var command = [
                    'composite',
                    '-geometry', 'x'+size+'+5',
                    '-dissolve', '50%',
                    '-gravity', 'east',
                    '-quality', 100,
                    watermark,
                    file,
                    file
                ];

                var textcommand = [
                    'convert',
                    file,
                    '-fill White',
                    '-gravity east -annotate +165+60',
                    '"FD_'+annotation+'"',
                    file
                ];

                //-draw "gravity south \
                //  fill black  text 0,12 'Copyright' \
                //   fill white  text 1,11 'Copyright' " \
                console.log(command.join(' '));
                exec(command.join(' '), function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                    // Do stuff with result here
                    console.log('watermarking done');
                    if (annotation) {
                        exec(textcommand.join(' '), function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                            console.log('annotating done');
                            resolve(file);
                        });
                    } else {
                        resolve(file);
                    }
                });
            });
        }catch(e) {
            reject("error while watermark")
        }

    };
};


const sendRequest = (rawParams, resizedParams, originKey, bucket, succeesCallback) => {
    console.log("send request with params");
    let params = {};
    params['Key'] = originKey;
    params['Bucket'] = bucket;
    params['meta'] = rawParams.data.Metadata;
    params['thumbs'] = resizedParams;
    params['size'] = rawParams.data.ContentLength;

    var serialize = function(obj, prefix) {
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                var k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p, v = obj[p];
                str.push(typeof v == "object" ?
                    serialize(v, k) :
                encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
            }
        }
        return str.join("&");
    };

    var options = {
        hostname: config.hostname,
        port: config.port,
        path: '/upload/add',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    };
    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        succeesCallback();
    });
    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });
// write data to request body
    req.write(serialize(params));
    req.end();
};

const processResize = (values, filePath, bucket, succeesCallback) => {

    var resizeSmall = new Promise(getResizePromise(values[0].data, 130));
    var resizeBig = new Promise(getResizePromise(values[0].data, 460));
    var wFile = values[1].file;

    function putObjects(params) {
        return function (resolve, reject) {
            var options = {partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 1};
            s3.upload(params, options, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err, err.stack);
                    reject(err);
                } // an error occurred
                else  {// successful response
                    console.log("upload: ");
                    console.log(params);
                    resolve(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function getParams(file, size) {
        var uploadParams = {
            Bucket: config.thumbBucket,
            Key: filePath.replace(/\.jpg/i, '-'+size+'.jpg'),
            ACL: 'public-read'
        };
        uploadParams.Body = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync(file));
        return uploadParams;
    }

    function processWatermark(resizedFiles) {
        var id = '0';
        try {
            id = values[0].data.Metadata.id;
        }catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        var w1 = new Promise(getWatermarkPromise(resizedFiles[0], wFile, false));
        var w2 = new Promise(getWatermarkPromise(resizedFiles[1], wFile, id));
        Promise.all([w1, w2]).then(
            function (watermarked) {
                var uploadParams1 = getParams(watermarked[0], 130);
                var uploadParams2 = getParams(watermarked[1], 460);
                var u1 = new Promise(putObjects(uploadParams1));
                var u2 = new Promise(putObjects(uploadParams2));
                Promise.all([u1, u2]).then(function (results) {
                    sendRequest(values[0], results, filePath, bucket, succeesCallback);
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }
        ).catch(
            function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        );
    }

    Promise.all([resizeSmall, resizeBig]).then(
        function (vals) {
            processWatermark(vals);
        }
    ).catch(function (err) {
        console.log("resize error");
    });
};


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // Get the object from the event and show its content type
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key
    };
    console.log("start processing" + key);
    var wparams = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(params)); // deep cloning
    wparams.Key = config.watermark;

    var mainObject = new Promise(getObjectPromise(params, mainFile));
    var watermarkObject = new Promise(getObjectPromise(wparams, watermarkFile));
    Promise.all([mainObject, watermarkObject]).then(function (values) {
        processResize(values, key, bucket, function () {
            context.succeed();
        });
    }).catch(function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    })
};
```